# Code for detrended cross-correlation in R

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, cross-correlation

I want to code for Detrended Cross Correlation in R for time-series data but I'm still stuck. I don't know why the coefficient is not in range -1 : 1. I try to write following these equation below

[Measuring correlations between non-stationary series with DCCA coefficient](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.3984.pdf)

Detrened cross-correlation coefficient is calculated as detrended covariance of two dataset over detrened variance of two integrated series

[image]  (Equation 1)

For time-series {xt}, use integrated series profile

[image]   (Equation 2)

where the data must be detrended by local trend in box of size s

[image]  (Equation 3)

[image](Equation 4)

The X_hat is linear fit value evaluated by least square method

Detrended covariance of two profiles

[image] (Equation 5)

Average the covariance over all boxes

[image]  (Equation 6)

```
## data_1
    x= c(-1.042061,-0.669056,-0.685977,-0.067925,0.808380,1.385235,1.455245,0.540762 ,0.139570,-1.038133,0.080121,-0.102159,-0.068675,0.515445,0.600459,0.655325,0.610604,0.482337,0.079108,-0.118951,-0.050178,0.007500,-0.200622)
    ## data_2
    y= c(-2.368030,-2.607095,-1.277660,0.301499,1.346982,1.885968,1.765950,1.242890,-0.464786,0.186658,-0.036450,-0.396513,-0.157115,-0.012962,0.378752,-0.151658,0.774253,0.646541,0.311877,-0.694177,-0.412918,-0.338630,0.276635)
    ## window size = 6
    k=6
    DCCA_CC=function(x,y,k){
      ## calculate cumulative sum profile of all t
    xx<- cumsum(x - mean(x))  ## Equation 2
    yy<- cumsum(y - mean(y))  ## Equation 2

      ## Divide in to overlapping boxes of size k

  slide_win_xx = mat_sliding_window(xx,k)
  slide_win_yy = mat_sliding_window(yy,k)
  ## calculate linear fit value in each box 
  x_hat = t(apply(slide_win_xx,1,function(n) (lm(n~seq(1:length(n)))$fitted.values)))
  y_hat = t(apply(slide_win_yy,1,function(n) (lm(n~seq(1:length(n)))$fitted.values)))

##  Get detrend variance in each box with linear fit value (detrend by local trend).
  F2_dfa_x = c()
  F2_dfa_y = c()
  for(i in 1:nrow(x_hat)){
 ## Equation 4
    F2_dfa_x = c(F2_dfa_x,mean((xx[i:(i+k-1)]-x_hat[i,])^2))
  }
  for(i in 1:nrow(y_hat)){
## Equation 4
    F2_dfa_y = c(F2_dfa_y,mean((yy[i:(i+k-1)]-y_hat[i,])^2))
  }
  ## Average detrend variance over all boxes to obtain fluctuation
  F2_dfa_x = mean(F2_dfa_x) ## Equation 3
  F2_dfa_y = mean(F2_dfa_y) ## Equation 3

  ## Get detrended covariance of two profile
  F2_dcca = c()
  for(i in 1:nrow(x_hat)){
  ## Equation 5
    F2_dcca = c(F2_dcca,mean((xx[i:(i+k-1)]-x_hat[i,]) * (yy[i:(i+k-1)]-y_hat[i,]) ))
  }

## Equation 6
  F2_dcca = mean(F2_dcca)

## Calculate correlation coefficient 
  rho = F2_dcca / (F2_dfa_x * F2_dfa_y) ## Equation 1
  return(rho)
}

mat_sliding_window = function(xx,k){
## Function to generate boxes given dataset(xx) and box size (k)
  slide_mat=c()
  for (i in 1:(length(xx)-k+1)){
    slide_mat = rbind(slide_mat,xx[i:(i+k-1)] )
  }
  return(slide_mat)
}

print(DCCA_CC(x,y,k)) ##This give me 3.392302
```

I'm not sure if something wrong in integrated profile.

Comment: There is a statistical question buried here. Perhaps if you translate your code into mathematics you will see what is wrong.

Comment: Alright, first I construct a profile from cumulative sum of x minus xbar. Second, I divided these integrated profile into overlapping boxes of size k; given T-k+1 number of boxes.

Comment: Third, in each box, linear fit trend is construct (x/y_hat). Fourth, Detrended variance (F2_dfa) is calculated in each box by detrending value with the line fit value, Fifth, Detrended variance is then averaged over all boxed

Comment: Next, the averaged detrened covariance (F2_dcca) of profile for two time series (x) and (y) is calculated following the paper. Finally, the correlation coefficient as F2_dcca / (F2_dfa_x * F2_dfa_y)

Comment: Please edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: may I know which package to install in order to perform the part "divide into overlapping" boxes of size k

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I finally find my mistake. It is before the final line of the DCCA_CC function.

instead of

```
rho = F2_dcca / (F2_dfa_x * F2_dfa_y)
```

It must be

```
rho = F2_dcca / sqrt(F2_dfa_x * F2_dfa_y)
```